# Minimizing $\|Av-\lambda v\|_2^2$ with respect to $\lambda$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, optimization, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, least-squares

In my textbook there is this exercise in linear least squares chapter:

> Let $A$ be a given $n\times n$ matrix and $v$ a specified $n$-vector. Find the value $\lambda^*$ that minimizes $\|Av-\lambda v\|_2^2$ with respect to $\lambda$. If the optimal residual happens to be zero, what does this imply about $b$ and $\lambda$?

For the second part of the exercise, I think $b$ and $\lambda$ need to be eigenvector and eigenvalue of $A$, so the residual can be zero.

For first part, I tried

$\rho=Av-\lambda v= \rho_R + \rho_N = Ab-\lambda b_R-\lambda b_N$

$\rho_R=Ab-\lambda b_R, \rho_N=-\lambda b_N$

$\|\rho\|_2^2=\|\rho_R\|_2^2+\|\rho_N\|_2^2=\|Ab-\lambda b_R\|_2^2 + \|-\lambda b_N\|_2^2= \|Ab-\lambda b_R\|_2^2 + \lambda^2 \|b_N\|_2^2$

I don't know how to continue.

Answer (score 2):

If $v$ is an eigenvector and $\lambda$ is its corresponding eigenvalue, $Av - \lambda v = \lambda v - \lambda v =0$. Likewise, if $v$ is not an eigenvector, then $(A - \lambda I) v \neq 0$ for any choice of $\lambda$ and therefore the optimal value is not zero.

As for minimizing the desired quantity with respect to $ \lambda$ (assuming our vector space is real; the complex case is similar), note that

$$\lVert A v - \lambda v \rVert^2 = \langle A v - \lambda v , A v - \lambda v \rangle = \langle Av, Av \rangle - 2 \lambda \langle v, Av \rangle + \lambda^2 \langle v, v \rangle$$

Since

$$\langle Av, Av \rangle - 2 \lambda \langle v, Av \rangle + \lambda^2 \langle v, v \rangle$$

is quadratic with respect to $\lambda$ and it opens upward ($\langle v,v \rangle \geq 0$), we can minimize it by finding its vertex (alternatively, take its derivative with respect to $\lambda$ and set it to zero; this is indeed the minimizer by convexity/first derivative test/second derivative test, take your pick). Using the derivative approach, the minimizer $\lambda^*$ satisfies $-2 \langle v,Av \rangle + 2 \lambda^* \langle v,v \rangle = 0$, for which you can solve for $\lambda^*$.

Answer (score 2):

We can take $\|v\|=1$ without loss of generality.

Then
$\|Av-\lambda v\|^2 = \|Av\|^2 -2 \operatorname{re} ( \lambda \langle Av , v \rangle )  + |\lambda|^2$. If we write $\lambda = x+iy$ then
the problem is to minimise
$\|Av\|^2 -2 x \operatorname{re}  \langle Av , v \rangle + 2y \operatorname{im}  \langle Av , v \rangle  + x^2 + y^2$. Solving these
equations gives $\lambda^* = \overline{\langle Av , v \rangle}$.
It is straightforward to compute the residual value of
$\|Av\|^2 - |\langle Av , v \rangle|^2$.

If the residual value is zero we have $Av=\lambda v$, hence $v$ is an eigenvector of $A$ corresponding to the eigenvalue $\lambda$.

Answer (score 0):

Yet another approach in addition to the other excellent general answers. Define vector $Av=b$. Then we want to find the $\lambda$ which minimizes $||b-\lambda v||^2$. Thus we want to find the scaling of the vector $v$ such that it is as close to $b$ as possible. Can you try convincing yourself that this is given by the projection of $b$ on the unit-vector on $v$? The projection is given as $${<b,v> \over <v,v>}={<Av,v> \over <v,v>}$$